# How can I set up mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I set up mod_rewrite?
My directory structure is bellow for(www.example.com)

```
index.php
user[directory]
   index.php [file in user directory]
.htaccess
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?url=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?url=$1
```

How to access `http://www.example.com/user`?

When I open `http://www.example.com/user` I get `http://www.example.com/user/?url=user`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file. A complete tutorial on htaccess for newbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# turn directory trailing slash off
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```